# Why does capacitor charge first, only then LED lights up?

Tags: led, capacitor

I kindly ask for your help on the following question;

Setup: We have a 100F, 2,7 V capacitor connected to the power supply (2,7 V). To that capacitor, we connect a blue LED (2,5 V) in parallel.

**Question:** Why does capacitor charge first and only when the capacitor is charged, then the LED lights up?

Additional explanation: Google is full of examples on discharging the capacitor over the LED, but examples the other way around are very few. The power supply can clearly provide enough amperage, so this must be related to potential difference, created by the capacitor. Please, direct me to the point of solution, so I can better understand the basics.

Connection diagram: 
[image]

Comment: This question is missing information. The cell is shown as an ideal voltage source with an infinite current capacity. That means that nothing else determines the voltage: it is always 2.7. The capacitor would instantly charge (with infinite current) to whatever the voltage source decides.

Comment: @BorisCerar You just earned yourself a second downvote with that kind of language

Answer (score 4):

Because this is what your circuit really looks like.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcc7VC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An LED is still a diode. You must apply a threshold voltage across it before it starts to conduct. As such, when power is first applied the voltage across the capacitor and LED is zero. The capacitor is setting the voltage across the LED.

After that, the LED can not start to turn on until the voltage across the capacitor reaches the LED's threshold voltage.

The battery (and connections and wiring) have a real resistance, as such it takes time for the capacitor to charge. With a large capacitor like you have indicated, the RC charge time to 66% voltage is RC, that is.. 100 times the battery resistance seconds.

Answer (score 3):

...because the voltage source is not an ideal source, i.e. it has non-Zero internal series resistance.

That means when a lot of current is drawn (e.g. at beginning of the capacitor's charging cycle) the voltage at the terminals are well below 2.7V. As the capacitor is more and more charged the remaining charging current goes to 0 and accordingly also voltage drop across internal resitance decreases, i.e. external voltage goes to 2.7V.

The LED needs about 2.5V (a little bit less) to start to conduct. Only when it is conducting it lights up.

Note that a LED normally should be operated with current limiting, i.e. either a current source or a voltage source with series resistor. Otherwise the LED may be damaged.

Comment: The current at the beginning of charging cycle is around 4,5A. But even when the charging current reduces to 1,5 A, the LED is not fully lit. Why? We have enough current.

Comment: @BorisCerar. Even with 1.5 A you are still at the slope of the RC curve. Meaning that the voltage over the capacitor and also over the led is still in the threshold value of the led.

Comment: @BorisCerar: e.g. if internal resistance of non-ideal voltage source is 0.25Ω the voltage drop @ 1.5A is 0.375V, i.e. you get only 2.7V - 0.375V = 2.325V which is not enough to fully light the LED

Answer (score -1):

The capacitor and the LED are in parallel, so the voltage across the capacitor is the voltage across the LED. If the capacitor is discharged, the voltage across it is zero, so the LED cannot light.

Comment: @BorisCerar The LED cannot light until the voltage across it equals or exceeds its forward voltage. The LED and capacitor are in parallel. Therefore the LED cannot light until the capacitor charges to at least the LED's forward voltage.

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem. The voltage source determines the voltage, so the capacitor _can not_ have any other voltage than 2.7. To answer this problem, you need to take non-ideal components into consideration.

Comment: @pipe Actually, *you* need to take non-ideal components into consideration. Your claim that "the voltage source determines the voltage" is false. There is no issue with treating the LED and the capacitor as ideal for simplicity.